# How to use \MakeUppercase in \sectionlinesformat together with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, bookmarks

Is it possible to use `\MakeUppercase` in KOMA-Script’s `\sectionlineformat` to get uppercase section headers without breaking `hyperef`’s PDF bookmarks? The following example shows the problem. The `\addsec` headline in the bookmarks points to the firs page (i.e. what `hyperref`/TeX thinks is a “a fixed one”).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
   \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip#2\relax #3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
%      \@hangfrom{\hskip#2\relax #3}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#4}}{#4}}% doesn't work
   }{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip#2\relax #3}{#4}%
   }%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\MakeUppercase}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test
\clearpage
\addsec{Addsec on page 2}
Text
\end{document}
```

The `\texorpdfstring` trick doesn’t work. I already found out that `hypperref` seems to “inject” something in the `#4` argument of `\sectionlinesformat` where the `\MakeUppercase` happens to break the “injection”.

Is it possible to use `\MakeUppercase` here at all, or is there another way of getting upper case section headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `\phantomsection`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
   \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip#2\relax #3}{\phantomsection\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
   }{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip#2\relax #3}{#4}%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test
\clearpage
\addsec{Addsec on page 2}
Text
\clearpage
\addsec{Addsec on page 3}
Text
\end{document}
```

Loading `bookmark` is usually recommended, but it's not essential for the solution.

Comment: That was easy. Thanks! Could you pleas explain a bit, why the phantom section is nessecary here?

Comment: @Tobi The title wants to go in the bookmarks, so an anchor needs to be made. I don't know what `scrartcl` does normally or whether `hyperref` patches it. A good start would be to look at the meaning of `\sectionlinesformat` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply! It seems like `hyperref` uses `\NR@ssect`, but adding `\MakeUppercase` at a lower level is impossible since the “knowledge” of the section type isn’t available anymore. I stuck to adding the `\phantomsection` and it worked fine.